# Invalid RGBA color "ro" in matplotlib while using the plot() function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to use the `Figure.figure.plot()` function from matplotlib

```
figplot = fig.add_subplot(111)
print(lines[2].get_xdata()[0])
print(lines[2].get_ydata()[0])
figplot.plot(lines[2].get_xdata()[0], lines[2].get_ydata()[0], c='ro')
```

but upon trying to execute this, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 259, in resize
    self.draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2647, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 783, in draw
    lc_rgba = mcolors.to_rgba(self._color, self._alpha)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 177, in to_rgba
    rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 233, in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle
    raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'ro'
```

I've noticed that for scatter plots, the colors have to be an array, but this isn't a scatter plot. 
the values of  `lines[2].get_xdata()[0]` and `lines[2].get_ydata()[0]` is as follows:

```
0.5766199490353112
1648.0609161647387
```

Is there any way to find out what's going wrong? I'm using tkinter along with matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ro` is color-marker code. You should remove `c=`:

```
figplot.plot(lines[2].get_xdata()[0], lines[2].get_ydata()[0], 'ro')
```

Or maybe specify color without the marker `o`:

```
figplot.plot(lines[2].get_xdata()[0], lines[2].get_ydata()[0], c='r')
```